# How to skip Registeration Screen in Android?

Tags: android, authentication, android-activity

I am making Registeration/Login module in Android locally, using Sqlite database.Here is the code :

```
public class Registration extends Activity {

Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
//EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;
DbManager manager = new DbManager(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    // Assignment of UI fields to the variables
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    //inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    // btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);
    setActionBar();

    //set OnClickListener

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String user_name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
        //  final String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            boolean invalid = false;

            if(user_name.equals("")&&password.equals(""))
            {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter necessary credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

                        else

                            if(password.equals(""))
                            {
                                invalid = true;
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                                else

                                    if(user_name.equals(""))
                                    {
                                        invalid = true;
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your user name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    else
                                        if(invalid == false){
                                            String User[] = {user_name,password};
                                            // manager=new DbManager(this);)
                                            //if(manager.Login(email, password).equals(true));
                                            if (manager.Register(user_name, password))
                                            {
                                                if(user_name.equalsIgnoreCase(user_name)&&password.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
                                                {
                                                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Already registered, please login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            }

                                            else{
                                                Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Successfully registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                manager.Insert_Values_User(User);
                                                Intent i_register = new Intent(Registration.this, login.class);
                                                startActivity(i_register);
                                                finish();
                                            }

                                        }
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    login.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
    }
```

Login class is :

```
public class login extends Activity {
Button btnLogin;
Button btnLinkToRegister;

EditText inputPassword;
TextView loginErrorMsg;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login); 
 // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
  //  inputUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    setActionBar();

 // If login is successful
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Check Login
           // final String user_name = inputUserName.getText().toString();
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

        DbManager users = new DbManager(login.this);
        boolean invalid = false;

        if(password.equals(""))
        {
            invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter password ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


            else if(users.Login(password)){
                    if(password.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(login.this, "Successfully logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                 MainActivity.class);
                         startActivity(i);
                         finish();
                    }

                }
             else 
                 Toast.makeText(login.this,"Invalid Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             users.close();
            }
        });





 // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Registration.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });


}
```

I want Registration screen to be appeared, only if user is not registered. If he is regstered then application should directly open Login screen.
I have searched, but i could n't find how to that?? Any useful help will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider `Preferences`?

Comment: how to use sharedPreferences ? any helping simple tutorial regarding the query please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi good to hear that you new to Android App Development.

We can do this by the help of Shared Preferences. Shared preference is local db which user could not able to view like sqlite db. It not a much tough to create.

Do the following steps One By One. Add if not already available in Android Manifest.xml file under

```
 <android:name="com.yourpackage.MiApplication">
```

Add this one More class that I have created for you.

```
   import android.app.Application;

   import android.content.SharedPreferences;

  import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

  public class MiApplication extends Application {

public static final String PREFERENCE_NAME = "misession";

private static final String SESSION_KEY = "login_status";

private static SharedPreferences miPreferences;
private static Editor miEditor;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    miPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    miEditor = miPreferences.edit();
}

public static void setSession(boolean session) {
    miEditor.putBoolean(SESSION_KEY, session);
    miEditor.commit();
}

public static boolean getSession() {
    return miPreferences.getBoolean(SESSION_KEY, false);
}
```

}

use setSession and set to true when you successfully logged in. and use the getSession to check the login status. if true then open main page else open reg. page.

Note:  `<android:name="com.yourpackage.MiApplication">`this line is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference for that..

Like this..

```
SharedPreferences wmbPreference;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

in onCreate

```
wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
boolean isActivated=wmbPreference.getBoolean("ISACTIVATED", false);
```

If `ISACTIVATED` is false then you can show the login screen else skip it..

And you can edit the shared preference once the user is logged in like this..

```
editor = wmbPreference.edit();
editor.putBoolean("ISACTIVATED", true);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: i am new to Android, how can i use SharedPreference to skip Registeratin screen ???

Comment: try this to skip registration screen.. if(ISACTIVATED){setContentView(R.layout.your_next_activity);}else{setContentView(R.layout.your_registration_activity);}

Comment: app stops unexpectidly :\

Comment: or else try this...if(ISACTIVATED){Intent to new activity}else{setContentView‌​(Intent to registration activity);}

Comment: yes. sorry to say i am not getting expected result , Can you please post code solution you are asking for ??

Comment: what is the problem now??

Comment: The accepted answer itself was what i said @user3559862 .. Atleast give my answer an upvote..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
public static String KEY = "SESSION";

    // Method to store the preference :
public static void saveUserId(String mUserId, Context context) {
    Editor editor = context
            .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("mUserId", mUserId);
    editor.commit();
}
    // Method to get the preferences :
public static String getUserId(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences savedSession = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY,
            Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return savedSession.getString("mUserId", "");
}
```

Keep the above methods in your app's Utils class to keep the code organized.
  You can save the preference like this once the user logged in:

```
  Utils.saveUserId("your id",YourActivity.this);
```

To check whether the user is logged in,
 You can do something like this.

```
 If (Utils.getUserId(YourActivity.this).equals(""))
 {
   // User has not logged in. Show Registration screen here.

 }
 else
 {
 // User logged in : Skip Registration screen here.
 }
```